# Html website page redirection according to domain name?

Tags: html, redirect, web

there I have a website with 2 domains pointing to the same IP address. One is a (.com) the other a (.co.za) The entire site is the same for both domains but I would like to be able to direct traffic to different contact pages according to the domain that they have used. For example, if they got to the site using (.com) I would like them to see my American and Canadian contact details (which is on one page). But if they got to the site using (.co.za) I would like them to see my South African contact details which I would like to be on another page not showing the American and Canadian details.

Could anyone please advise me on the best way to get this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: What server are you using?  Perhaps a simple php redirect script might work best?

Comment: are you looking for Server side or client side redirect?

Comment: I was actually thinking client side maybe javascript. But if PHP will work better then great. I am using Apache 2 on Linux Debian 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

I created a page called contact-red.html

with the following javascript code:

```
    loc1 = window.location.href;


function redir (event){
    window.location.href = "https://www.createmedia.co.za/contact-creative-media2.html"
}

function redir2 (event){
    window.location.href = "https://www.createmediacompany.com/contact-creative-media.html"
}

if (loc1 === "https://www.createmedia.co.za/contact-red.html") {
    redir();
}
 else {
     redir2();
 };
```

It redirects according to the URL of the visitor.

Thanks